# a function that works with arrays

Tags: operation

I need your help to write a function that does the following:

It recieves 2 pointers (type double) ;

one points on the first element of an array, the ther one points behind the array. This pointer cannot be dereferenced.

If the pointers point on two adjacent array elements, the output is the value of the first pointer. Otherwise, the function is called from the first element to the element in the middle, and from that middle element to the end, and out of these two values, the higher one is the output.

Indexing is forbidden (yep, it's homework). Also this type of thing is forbidden -> *(p+1). It has to work exactly as described (if not, i get no points).

I really hope I managed to make it understandable since I don't even get it myself? I'm told it's super simple though, can be written in like 10 lines of code, but I just can't get the hang of it? I know how to write the usual function that finds the usual max number, but that's obviosly not what this problem is asking for...

Here are some examples of what's supposed to work:

```
double arr[] = {4.3, 15.1, 2.2, -3.4, 18.1, 1.1, 3.0};
printf("%g", parallel_max(arr, arr+7));
```

expected output: 18.1

```
double arr[] = {4.3, 15.1, 2.2, 18.2, -3.4, 1.1, 3.0};
printf("%g", parallel_max(arr, arr+7));
```

expected output: 18.2

```
double arr[] = {3, 1, 2};
printf("%g", parallel_max(arr, arr+3));
```

expected output: 3

```
double arr[] = {42.42};
printf("%g", parallel_max(arr, arr+1));
```

expected output: 42.42

please help?

Comment: How does this even compile?

Comment: @stackptr well... it... doesn't? :-)

Comment: `double* arr(size+1)`-- what is this supposed to mean? This is a syntax violation. You might start by writing what you think the code in `main()` that calls `parallel_max()` should look like.

Comment: @DavidBowling i know it doesn't work at all.. i just didn't know how to write that it's supposed to be a pointer that points behind the array :-(

Comment: @DavidBowling ohhh so that's how you do it, thanks! Alright then, but how do I use that later in the code?

Comment: You can't specify that a pointer points to the end of an array in a function prototype; see the update on my previous comment. For `double arr[]` a pointer to the first element would be `double *start = arr;` and a pointer to one-past the end would be `double *end = start + sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;`. – David Bowling 11 mins ago

Comment: First, get the definition for `arr[]` out of the function and move it to `main()` (or the calling function). You can use `sizeof` to find the number of bytes in an array within the defining scope of the array. Then pass these two pointers (`start` and `end`) to your function.

Comment: i think it would be a homework on divide and divide and conquer method of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your homework, you want a recursive solution; where the max of an array with 1 element is that element, and the max of an array with more than 1 element is, recursively, the max of the left half or the max of the right half.

```
// NOT TESTED
double parallel_max(double *a, double *b) {
    if (b - a == 1) return *a; // they're consecutive
    double *c = a + ((b - a) / 2); // c points to middle
    double left = parallel_max(a, c);
    double right = parallel_max(c, b);
    return (left > right) ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: That's.... exaclty what I needed!!! I never thought it would be that.. simple? Well, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Keyword, I think, is **recursive**.